# Are global variables cleaned by garbage collector in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

In the following JS code, will `example1` or `example2` be ever cleaned by the garbage collector? Will their memory be ever released by the GC? I am dealing with memory leaks and I have a few such instances in my code.

```
example1 = 'Outside a function'

function sample(x){
    example2 = 'Inside a function'
}
sample(1)
```

From what I understand is neither of the variables will ever be cleaned by Garbage collector because they are treated as global variables. Might sound like a trivial question but finding memory leaks is like finding a needle in a haystack

Comment: Your question is unclear. A garbage collector doesn't clear variables. Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @JörgWMittag have made some edits, does that make more sense?

Comment: Not really. Like I wrote: a garbage collector doesn't clean variables. So, it is unclear what you mean by "In the following JS code, will `example1` or `example2` be ever cleaned by the garbage collector?" and "neither of the variables will ever be cleaned by Garbage collector".

Comment: First off, stop using variables that aren't explicitly declared in some scope.  That's just a BAD practice and, if you are running strict mode like you should be, it will even be an error. Repeat - bad practice. Explicitly declare every variable in the desired scope with `var`, `let` or `const`. The contents of a variable in ANY scope will be cleaned up by the garbage collector ONLY when that variable can no longer be reached by any code that is still in play.  So, if you're variable is still reachable by some of your code, then the garbage collector will not clean up that variable's contents.

Comment: The usual way of attacking memory leaks is to record heap snapshots and then compare them to fine out what the differences are between two snapshots and see if that's what you expect or if something seems to be continually accumulating.  Here's [how to do that](https://www.google.com/search?q=heap+snapshot+nodejs&oq=heap+snapshot+nodejs) in nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

The heap has two main segments, the New Space and the Old Space. The New Space is where new allocations are happening; it is fast to collect garbage here and has a size of ~1-8MBs. Objects living in the New Space are called Young Generation. The Old Space where the objects that survived the collector in the New Space are promoted into - they are called the Old Generation. Allocation in the Old Space is fast, however collection is expensive so it is infrequently performed .

You need understand few thinks, like:

1 - The garbage collector builds a list of "roots". Roots usually are global variables to which a reference is kept in code. In JavaScript, the "window" object is an example of a global variable that can act as a root. The window object is always present, so the garbage collector can consider it and all of its children to be always present (i.e. not garbage).

2 - All roots are inspected and marked as active (i.e. not garbage). All children are inspected recursively as well. Everything that can be reached from a root is not considered garbage.

3- All pieces of memory not marked as active can now be considered garbage. The collector can now free that memory and return it to the OS.

So about your questions:

```
From what I understand is neither of the variables will ever be cleaned by Garbage collector because they are treated as global variables. 
Might sound like a trivial question but finding memory leaks is like finding a needle in a haystack
```

You are correct.